# Inserting into a closure table with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to get my head around using a closure table in PHP/MySQL specifically Codeigniter, for an application I am building that has areas, and each area can have a number of locations, departments etc.

I have been using http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data to learn how it works.

And I have also been using https://gist.github.com/dazld/2174233 to help me get to grips with accessing the data, which I can do fine, I've adapted the methods to pull out data as I need it, which is all good.

But now I'm trying to insert data, and I cannot get my head around it. So I've adapted the add method from the above script, but I don't understand it, and I cannot get it to work

Heres the area table

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| area_id    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| area_title | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| area_name  | varchar(40) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| org_id     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Heres the area_hierarchy table

```
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ancestor   | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| descendant | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| lvl        | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Heres the method I'm trying to use to add entries:

```
public function add($node_id, $target_id) {

    $sql = 'SELECT ancestor, '.$node_id.', lvl+1
            FROM area_hierarchy
            WHERE descendant = '.$target_id.'
            UNION 
            SELECT '.$node_id.','.$node_id.',0';

    $query = 'INSERT INTO area_hierarchy (ancestor, descendant,lvl) ('.$sql.')';

    $result = $this->db->query($query);

    return $result;

}
```

So specifically, what is $node_id, and $target_id.

What is the lvl+1?

So if I add a new top level area, what data do I pass to this method?

The query also fails and gives a syntax error after UNION

Comment: Node id is the new node (child) you are adding, target id is the parent (ancestor) node. The union is to deal with the self reference, which you should always have with closures. If I want to add D under B, I need to select all ancestors of B and create a relationship to D, I also need to create a self reference as per the union for D = D with a level of zero.

Comment: In your example, say you have 10 areas, 1,2,3,4,5 and they have the exact same primary key. They should all exist on the root level, you'd add those areas in first, then you'd call `add($areaId)` for each node. Then you want 6,7,8 to be children of 3. You'd then call `add($areaId, 3)` for each of those areas. Finally, we want 9 and 10 be be children of 8. We call `add($areaId, 8)`. If you need help with why your query is failing or not working as expected you need to give us the error and expected outcome.

Comment: Thank you, good explanation. I'll go away and experiement

Comment: Try doing `INSERT INTO (...) SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM (SELECT id AS col1, 3 AS col2, parent_id+1 AS col3 FROM acl_role_hierarchies WHERE parent_id = 0 UNION SELECT 3 AS col1,3 AS col2,0 AS col3) AS res`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$node_id` would be the value of the `area_id` column from the `area` table. Presumably, that's a row you just added to the area table.

`$target_id` would be the value of the `area_id` column from another row in the `area` table, the row you are identifying as the "parent", the direct ancestor.

The `lvl+1` is the generation, or level in the hierarchy... how "far away" a descendant is from it's parent.

If you are adding a new "top level" area, you would use `$node_id` for `$target_id`.

One of the best ways to understand this is to look at the "current state" of the `area_hierarchy` table, and what the "end state" of the table should be when a node is added.

With just a top level node in the tree, area_id=11, the area_hierarchy table would look like this:

```
 ancestor descendant lvl 
 -------- ---------- ---
 11       11         0
```

If we add another row to the area table, area_id=22, as a child (direct descendant) of area_id=11, we need to add these two rows to area_hierarchy:

```
 ancestor descendant lvl 
 -------- ---------- ---
 11       22         1
 22       22         0
```

If we add another row to area table, area_id=333, as a child of area_id=22, we need to add these rows to the area_hierarchy table:

```
 ancestor descendant lvl 
 -------- ---------- ---
 11       333        2
 22       333        1
 333      333        0
```

Notice that the first two rows we need to add look a lot like the rows that already exist in the table, where descendant=22.  The difference is that descendant on the new rows is 333 instead of 22, and value of lvl is one more than it was on the rows we already had in the table.

And that third row we need to add is the reference to itself. Just like we had area_id=11 as a "parent" of itself.

That third row we get from the part after the UNION. The first two rows we get by copying the rows already in `area_hierarchy`, replacing the value of the descendant column with the id of the node we're adding (333), and increasing lvl by 1.

Once you understand what rows need to be added, and how we can derive them by copying/modifying other rows in the table, then the SQL starts to make sense.

---

You would accomplish adding those three rows for area_id=333, calling the add function:

```
 add(333,22);
```

If you want to add area_id=4444 as a new "top level" in the hierarchy:

```
 add(4444,4444);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, very informative and makes it clear. Now I do have one more question, should I index the closure table with a column, say the ID of the organisation?

Comment: @frobak: Yes, add appropriate indexes. Indexes serve a couple of important purposes. For one, indexes can be used to enforce unique constraints. You'd add a unique constraint if you wanted the database to prevent a duplicate row being added to the table. Consider for example executing a second call `add(4444,4444)`. What end state do you want in the database? Would you want two *identical* rows in the area_hierarchy table? The other purpose of indexes is improving performance. Which indexes are most suitable depends on the statements which statements will be executed.